# Apache Architecture

Tags: apache, architecture

I'm trying to understand the basic mechanism at which apache works internally (for academic purposes).
I have no experience in open-source projects so I'm having problems seeing the general picture as most posts discuss how to configure Apache rather than its architecture.
The few examples I saw were very old, and more about the modules (not the core).

So, the points I'm concerned about are:

1. Core main files: What are the files doing the main functionality
   in the core? how do they interact between then (specific functions)?
2. Global functions:
   What are the global (the most important) functions in Apache?
   What function listens to the server port (e.g 80)?
   Where does spawning new threads for new incoming requests happen?
3. Interaction with modules:
   What functions of the core are responsible for passing control to modules?
   What is interaction mechanism exactly?

Any other points that might help understanding the whole picture would be also
great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Apache Platform and Architecture](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=705689) - a chapter taken from a book [The Apache Modules Book: Application Development with Apache](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132409674):

> Nick Kew provides an overview of the
>   Apache architecture, and its
>   relationship to the operating system,
>   the roles of the principal components:
>   MPMs, APR, and modules, configuration
>   basics, and other architectures and
>   object information.

You also can take a look at [this](http://www.academic.marist.edu/~jzbv/architecture/Projects08/ApacheServerArchitectureProject.ppt) presentation, might be helpful as well.

Comment: Good presentation. One anecdote that could give the idea is how the name "Apache" came into being. Given the number of fixes that were added, it was initially deemed to be "A patchy" server ;-)

Comment: I'm checking the book and the presentation.. seems very useful so far.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:
Apache Tomcat Architecture

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/architecture/index.html

Comment: I am actually looking for Apache itself, and not the Apache Tomcat. Is Tomcat's architecture similar? Can it be helpful in any way?